# Why my servo always blocks?

Tags: servo

I try to control a servo with my Pi.

Here is the python code I use :

```
        # Import libraries
        import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
        import time

        # Set GPIO numbering mode
        GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BOARD)

        # Set pin 11 as an output, and define as servo1 as PWM pin
        GPIO.setup(11,GPIO.OUT)
        servo1 = GPIO.PWM(11,50) # pin 11 for servo1, pulse 50Hz

        # Start PWM running, with value of 0 (pulse off)
        servo1.start(0)

        # Loop to allow user to set servo angle. Try/finally allows exit
        # with execution of servo.stop and GPIO cleanup :)

        try:
            while True:
                #Ask user for angle and turn servo to it
                angle = float(input('Enter angle between 0 & 180: '))
                servo1.ChangeDutyCycle(2+(angle/18))
                time.sleep(0.5)
                servo1.ChangeDutyCycle(0)

        finally:
            #Clean things up at the end
            servo1.stop()
            GPIO.cleanup()
            print("Goodbye!")
```

And here is the problem : whatever the angle I choose (10, 45, 90 ,180...), the motor turns in the same direction until it reaches the tilt position.

I have 5 motors, it's the same with all of them.
I also tried to change the wires.
Here is the motors reference : https://www.amazon.fr/gp/product/B07BF7B69M

Here is a picture that show the pins I use
[image: servo connection]

Does anybody have an idea?
Tia

Comment: The code appears to be okay.  I suggest you look at the wiring.  Post a clear photo showing the wiring.

Comment: hi @joan, I just add a photo

Comment: That looks okay.  Try `sudo pigpiod` then `pigs s 17 700` then `pigs s 17 1500` then `pigs s 17 2200`

Comment: @joan Hi, I test your commands and it turns without blocking :). Are you able to explain me?

Comment: Not really.  pigpio sends more accurate signals (better timing), but that would not explain what you are seeing.